# Get $_POST from type=file

Tags: php

I have form for example:

```
<input type="text" />

<input type="file" />

<input type="submit" />
```

You have to fill the text and the file, if you dont fill the text for example you have an error message, but I want to preserve what the user filled in the file's input.
How to do it with `$_POST` or somthing else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to preserve what the user filled in the file's input.

Impossible.

Comment: Sure 100%? what is the reason?

Comment: Since it is, as far as the browser is concerned, a new page with a new form. If you let pages specify any file path they like for a default value of a file input, then it becomes trivial to lift files from the user's hard disk without their knowledge. As security holes go, it is the size of Belgium.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE:

$_POST is not the superglobal that will provide information related to 'file' inputs'. Look into you $_FILES superglobal for that kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the "name" attribute of each input to something different:

```
<input type="text" name="title" />

<input type="file" name="picture"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit_button_1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_button_2"/>
```

Setting the name attribute of the submit input can be useful when you have several of them and you want to know on which one you clicked.

Comment: Hey, of course I know it I just ask how to do it, because if you will take $_POST['picture'] and put it in the value it wont work. that why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

whatever user submits from client-side is not controlled by server-side, but you can:

- use javascript to "scan" the extension name of file (.php), and prevent other files from not being able to be submitted. However this doesn't stop people renaming other files to .php.
- the question is what you gonna do with the submitted php file? keep it in database? or execute it? you need to scan its content to make sure it doesn't contain malicious code. I am not very sure how php can do this, though.